# Nuxtjs SSR error "Request path contains unescaped characters" for URL containing arabic characters

Tags: nuxt.js

For nuxt When using SSR, URLs containing arabic characters throw an error: "Request path contains unescaped characters"

example: when navigating to "[http://localhost:4000/خضار-بخلطة-الطماطم](http://localhost:4000/%D8%AE%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%AE%D9%84%D8%B7%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%85)" for SSR I get the following:

```
TypeError [ERRUNESCAPEDCHARACTERS]
Request path contains unescaped characters

URI : /%D8%AE%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%AE%D9%84%D8%B7%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%85

REQUEST METHOD | GET
HTTP VERSION | 1.1
CONNECTION | keep-alive
```

NB: client rendering works fine

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In asyncData I was doing an API call that uses `context.params.slug`. 
The paramas were not UTF-8 Encoded, so I added: `encodeURIComponent(context.params.slug)`,
this way I was no more receiving the error

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in vue-router that prevent non unicode urls to work properly on initial page load. It was merged into vue router, but its not yet released.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/pull/2375

Once new vue-router version will be released a fix will be merged into nuxt -> https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/3841

Comment: When do you think the bug fix will be released?
What do you suggest? change the mode to SPA and than when the fix is released update or I have to figure out another framework?

Comment: @AnaHoua i have asked and they said they plan to release vue router soon, but dont know date yet. After router will be released it will be in nuxt asap. If you are in dev phase yet then switching to spa mode will be fine till fix

Comment: I am still in dev phase so i think i will continue with nuxt with spa until update, thanks for the answer